# Zend Framework with htaccess

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, redirect, error-handling

I developed a website using Zend Framework. In order to handle errors, I want to add to the htaccess file the following lines so I can redirect the user to the corresponding every time there is an error.

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
```

so my htaccess file now in the `/public` folder looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Rewrite rules for Zend Framework

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php

# Security: Don't allow browsing of directories
Options -Indexes
# PHP settings
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag register_globals off
php_flag short_open_tag on

ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
```

However it seems not to work and it doesn't redirect me to any of these pages and instead it displays this classic error page.

> Server error
>
> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://www.mysite.com/wesgtsgsfd/sgsdf. It may be down for maintenance
>   or configured incorrectly.
>
> Here are some suggestions: Reload this web
>   page later. HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected
>   condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil
>   the request.

Does anybody have an idea about to fix my htaccess file so Apache can handle the errors properly and redirect them to the error page according to the error type.

Comment: Welcome to SO. ;-) A short comment on question submission and formatting. Note that as you type (!) your questions, you can see a preview of your how your question will actually appear once you submit. It might be useful for you to take a look at the [Markdown formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Again, welcome!

Comment: Typically, all requests are routed to the ZF app using a set of standard .htaccess rules. Then errors - including 404, 500, etc - are handled by the ErrorController. Are you saying that you explicitly want to handle them at the Apache (rather than ZF) level?

Comment: i know that the ErrorController is an option to handle errors. however i dont really know how to use the errorcontroller (how to intercept errors and redirect them to the error controller in zend)
so i thought may be htaccess will be an easier option

Comment: Nice job on the formatting. ;-)

Comment: As others have noted, I would handle errors via `ErrorController`. Note that for a default ZF setup, the `ErrorController` will automatically (!) be invoked to handle the errors you cite. So minimal usage requires nothing extra. To tweak the handling for each type of error does actually require tweaking the controller and scripts. But it's not that hard and very instructive. ;-) Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is already solved in ZF's Error Controller.

See the `Error_Controller`, `Error_Controller::errorAction()` sources and the corresponding view scripts. You may easily add another view scripts using simple conditions there or switching the layout:

```
$this->getHelper('layout')->setLayout('custom404');
```

Comment: i fixed the problem. i was able to make the ErrorController work, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Apache can't handle errors thrown by your ZF app. This is because all requests are going to the index.php. its not difficult to customise the error pages in ZF. Plus you can keep the standard layout with ease. A [quick read](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler) will explain how errors are handled and its quite easy to customise the error page.